# Regarding variable initialization order

Tags: language-agnostic, initialization

I'd like to know what's the default approach for those times when you need a variable to have been set in order for a given method/another variable initialization to work.

Like this:

Everything works if I initialize `var A` *after* `var B`. But not the other way around. I wrote the constructor, so I'll do that myself, but I'm not really sure where the code that tests for `var B`'s existence should be. Or even if it should exist at all, for I have written the constructor and *I* initialize the values the order I see fit, but I feel it's a little insecure because it is not very robust in case anything changes.

Mind you, I'm talking about **instance variables**, if that helps.

FA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be influenced by the reason why `a` must be set before `b`.

**Explicit Object Dependencies**

If the reason is that `b` depends upon `a`, then the simplest thing to do is to make that dependency explicit at the time that `b` is created.  For example, if `a` and `b` were objects then:

```
var a = new A(...);
var b = new B(a, ...);
var op = new Operation(b);
op.perform();
```

In this way, it is not possible to initialize the objects out of order.  Note that `A` and `B` could be newly introduced wrapper objects that contain the original operation parameters.

**Fluent Interface**

If the reason is that the operation itself must know the value of `a` in order to perform some configuration in preparation for the arrival of `b`, then the operation constructor could be replaced by a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface):

```
Operation op = Operation.withA(a).withB(b);
op.perform();
```

We must take care to define this fluent interface in such a way that `withB` can only be called after `withA` has been called.  For example:

```
public class Operation {

    private final C _c;
    private final B _b;

    private Operation(C c, B b) {
        _c = c;
        _b = b;
    }

    public static BStep withA(final A a) {
        return new BStep() {
            public Operation withB(B b) {
                C c = setUpStateDependentUponA(a);
                return new Operation(c, b);
            }
        };
    };

    public interface BStep {
        Operation withB(B b);
    }

    public void perform() {
        // do something with _c and _b
    }

}
```

Here, `C` has been introduced to capture that state that is dependent upon `a` alone prior to the arrival of `b`.  Note how the constructor of `Operation` is not visible to client code and that `withB` cannot possibly be called until after `withA` has been called.

Answer (score 1):

I check before each time I access the variable, but if it is an instance variable and you initialize B in the constructor you should be safe. I use something like-

```
if (isset(var B)
{ do something with var A }
else 
{ error handler }
```

or

```
try 
    {
        if (isset(var B))
            do something with a;
        else
            throw new Exception("attribute B has not been set.");
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return NULL;
    }
```